# How do I remove the page title only from the front page?

Tags: 8

I have created a basic page and assigned it to the front page. Now I would like to remove the title shown in the front page.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Edit the Page Title Block and set it to not show on <front>.

Comment: Are you using the page title block? Also, are you using the default front page or have you made your own?

Answer (score 2):

The Title is a Block now in Drupal 8. You can edit the Page Title Block and set it to show on all paths except for `<front>` to hide it from the front page.